# Python 3.6 - Find a word in a soup.findAll() string

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is a basic example of a code that I'm hoping will help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('URLs.csv', newline='') as f_urls:
csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)

for line in csv_urls:
    page = requests.get(line[0])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for results in soup.findAll('a', {'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
        if "Scientist" in results:
            continue # Won't this continue just loop back to the for results in...loop, not the for line in csv_urls loop?
        else:
            print(results.text)
```

...where the URLs in the CSV file are:

```
https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=data+scientist%2C+data+analyst%2C+python&l=Canada&jt=fulltime&start=20
https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=data+scientist,+data+analyst,+python&l=Canada&jt=fulltime
```

...so in the context of this code, it starts by reading the first URL and finds all the job titles on that page. If any of the job titles in the scraped table contain the word "Scientist" (any of them), it should continue back to the “for line in csv_urls:” line and start over again at the next URL in the list. If they don't contain the word, then print the results.

This is a basic example and not what I'm using in my real code, but the application is the same. I think the problem may lie in where the continue is placed, because I need it to jump back to the "for line in csv_urls:" loop.

Hopefully this is more “on topic” for those invested. Thanks?

Comment: How about giving us a syntactically valid, executable example?

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce.

Comment: Just wondering if someone knows off the top of their head how to find a particular word in a table pulled from a website using BS4.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DYZ Thanks but my entire code is not necessary to answer my question. However let me create a script using the information I've provided to assist. Will update shortly

Comment: @DYZ See update above. Thanks!

Comment: Off topic? I’ve included what my desired behaviour should be, the problem at hand, and a reproducible code in my update. What exactly are you looking for from there? The “problem statement” is pretty clear. Maybe I’ll delete my original post so as to clear up any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call the `.text` or it will not match

```
for line in csv_urls:
    page = requests.get(line[0])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for results in soup.findAll('a', {'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
        if "Scientist" in results.text:
            break
            # stop this loop, continue to loop "csv_urls"
            # even the rest has no "Scientist"
        else:
            print(results.text)
```

Comment: Thanks it sort of worked, but not entirely the way I was hoping it would. I'm going to update my question with an example script that should help.

Comment: see my update above. Thanks!

Comment: you want to  stop the loop `for results in soup....` if found `Scientist` and continue to loop `for line in csv_urls:` ?

Comment: Correct. I’ve tried continue and break, but neither work correctly. Thoughts?

Comment: answer edited take a look.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was missing something (ie. break). Thanks a lot, I can work with my original code with that.